# Angularjs select not passing value

Tags: angularjs

I have a select dropdown in a form, it's not passing value to {{service}} object:

```
<select name="categoryId" ng-model="service.categoryId" ng-options="category.id as category.name for category in categories track by category.categoryId" required>
  <option value="0">-select a category-</option>
</select>
```

And I can't find a reason why, anyone?

Comment: what do you mean? you can't get the value of 'service.categoryId'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this example, it may help you:

```js
function theController($scope) {

  $scope.categories = [
    {name:'First', id:'A', categoryId: 1},
    {name:'Second', id:'B', categoryId: 2},
    {name:'Third', id:'C', categoryId: 3}
  ];
  
  $scope.service = $scope.categories[1];
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.22/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app>
    
  <div ng-controller="theController">
    <select name="categoryId" 
            ng-model="service" 
            ng-options="category as category.name for category in categories track by category.categoryId" required>
      <option value="">-select a category-</option>
    </select>
    <pre>categories = {{categories|json}}</pre>
    <pre>service = {{service|json}}</pre>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: I ended up using this: 

<option ng-repeat="category in categories" value="{{category.categoryId}}" ng-selected="{{option=='id'}}">{{category.name}}</option>

works too, thanks for your answer